# Add number to custom type and check if type still applies

Tags: typescript, types

I am currently building a chess library in TypeScript to try and deepen my knowledge and I found something I have no solution for. I am curious if this is a concept I just don't understand or if it's just not possible to achieve what I am trying.

My goal is to have the library as type safe as possible, but I am not sure if I am overdoing it.

I have the following type and interface:

```
export type ChessCoordinate = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7

export class Coordinates {
  x: ChessCoordinate
  y: ChessCoordinate

  constructor(x: ChessCoordinate, y: ChessCoordinate) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
  }
}
```

The idea is to use Coordinates to describe any field on the chess board e.g. `a1` would be `{x: 0, y: 0}`

A Coordinate with `{x: 3, y: 13}` should not be possible since it's not a valid chess field.

In my class for the pawn later on I have a method `possibleMoves()` that returns an array of Coordinates with possible fields the pawn can move to.

```
  possibleMoves(): Coordinates[] {
    // x and y are of type ChessCoordinates here
    const { x, y } = getCoordinatesFromPosition(this.position)

    let possibleMoves: Coordinates[] = [
      // Those all three throw errors
      new Coordinates(x, y + 1),
      new Coordinates(x + 1, y + 1),
      new Coordinates(x - 1, y + 1),
    ]

    return possibleMoves
  }
```

I'm getting a TypeError when I try to create the new Coordinates objects and it does make sense to me, since I am trying to add a `number` and a `ChessCoordinate` and want to fit that into a parameter of type `ChessCoordinate`: `TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ChessCoordinate'.`

But I am lost on how I would make it work. I want to do operations with the `ChessCoordinate` like moving it up/down/left/right on the axes and then check afterwards if it's still a valid `ChessCoordinate` i.e. still >0 and <8.

Is this something that's just not possible with types and can only be checked at runtime, meaning I should just do an if-clause that checks after increasing/decreasing the coordinate and then assert or cast to `ChessCoordinate` like so:

```
  possibleMoves(): Coordinates[] {
    const { x, y } = getCoordinatesFromPosition(this.position)
    
    let possibleMoves: Coordinates[] = []
    
    if ((y + 1) > 0 && (y + 1) < 8) {
      const newCoordinate = new Coordinates(x, (y + 1) as ChessCoordinate)
      possibleMoves.push(newCoordinate)
    }
    [...]
    return possibleMoves
  }
```

I am thinking there must be a better way to do this. Let me know what I am missing or if I am going down a completely different route and there is another approach that would work for me.

Comment: "Overdoing" something is really opinion based but I think you are overdoing it. Any time where you find yourself writing out a union of all the allowed numbers and you're going to be operating on those quite a lot, you should use the plain `number` type and check if they are in-bounds/valid. Otherwise you will find that half of your code is now casting things to the overly specific type you created.

Comment: And by the way, please do use the names `file` and `rank` instead of `x` and `y`, so Bobby Fischer can rest in his grave.

Comment: Yes I see and that makes sense to me, thank you! In that case I would then probably scrap the type for ChessCoordinates and the interface for Coordinates as well though since they have no use anymore and just use a plain array or tuple instead, or an object even. And about file and rank, yes. The naming felt wrong but I wasn't sure what they were called in chess terms last night.

Comment: You can't do math with types https://tsplay.dev/mx3XzN. Well, actually, [you can to a limited degree](https://itnext.io/implementing-arithmetic-within-typescripts-type-system-a1ef140a6f6f), but the high complexity complexity of that solution seems to be an ill fit for your use case.